# cant able to extract local data base file(.sdf file) by in using emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone development. I am working on an app in which local db is required. But I am unable to create it or am not able to understand from  where to start. I have tried many example but all in vein. I got some example running which ,in the emulator,  I can add data but if I start the emulator again then all the data is vanished and doesn’t show any data. I am not getting why. Is there any way that I can extract the db from emulator and if yes then where is it reside and how can I open it after extracting it. Is sqlite database is supported by windows phone if yes then is it the best option to use it.  For information I am using windows 8 and visual studio 2012. Please help me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: My blog post here should get you started: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Isolated Storage explorer provuded by microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx